# Spring boot errir

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, backend

I have build an spring boot app and connected it to database then I used crudRepository to implement the queries on the database but the app doesn't run and I can't figure out what is the error ?
this is the the github repository of the code
https://github.com/woodyinho/Ticket-Booking-Api

Comment: Please add more information like code stack trace or log messages. Otherwise we cannot help you Please also read this. https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: this is the the github repository of the code
https://github.com/woodyinho/Ticket-Booking-Api

Comment: do you have an error stacktrace when you run it?

Comment: So you are asking us for help solving your problem and you also think we should chase down the problematic code ourselves? Way to make it easy for people to provide help.

Comment: Yes I have stackrace error

Comment: Pls add it to the question

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself. As we've no control over what happens with your GitHub repository, the repository might be gone in the future, which would leave this question behind useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a hibernate dependency that is not needed.

Your dependencies should look like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. You should read how to use JpaRepository

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Your repo can look like

```
public interface TicketBookingDao extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer> {
}
```

Then you have methods like findById or deleteById etc.

Comment: Thank you, but I modified it and still get an error

Comment: I added Number 2 to my answer

Comment: Maybe you should read a tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ or a book

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls add `@Repository` to your DAO class:

```java
@Repository
public interface TicketBookingDao extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I added it now it gives me an error again
Field ticketBookingDao in com.example.RESTJPA.Services.TicketBookingService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.